# Cannot find type __ IntentHandling in scope with for dynamic content in Custom Intent Handler

Tags: swift, xcode, widgetkit, siri-intent

I have a WidgetKit widget with an intent handler. Currently it uses hard coded values and I'm trying to extend it to work with dynamic values.

I did this successfully on another project but am struggling with this one.

Here's what I've done:

1. Created an Intent Handler target
   [image: Screenshot]
2. Added a custom type
3. Added that type as a parameter
4. Added the intent definition as a member of the new target
   [image: Screenshot]
5. There is a custom class name for the intent
6. Custom code is successfully generated
   [image: Screenshot]
7. Set the `IntentHander` class to implement `ThemeSelectionIntentHandling`
   [image: Screenshot]

As you can see, this fails with the error `Cannot find type 'ThemeSelectionIntentHandling' in scope`.

The target that fails is the Intent Handler:

```
/Users/lewissmith/code/wtw-ios-app/WTWIntents/IntentHandler.swift:12:3: error: cannot find type 'ThemeSelectionIntentHandling' in scope
, ThemeSelectionIntentHandling {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

If I remove implementing `ThemeSelectionIntentHandling` then it builds as expected.

DTS won't help me because the project uses Cocoapods.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you done this step: [>In the File inspector, verify that the containing app, the widget extension, and the Intents extension all include the intent definition file.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget)

Comment: Which target is failing to build? (In Xcode, detailed build info is available in the Report navigator, cmd-9 shows it). This sounds like your generated class isn't included in some target where it's needed.

Comment: @leanne this is step 4 in my question right(?). The Intent Definition is a member of the main (containing) app, the widget extension and the intents extension. Am I missing something, does that look wrong to you?

Comment: @asyncawait it's the intent handler that fails compilation. I've added some extra screenshots and info to the question, thank you.

Comment: Gotcha - did your ThemeSelectionIntent.swift maybe not get added to your intent handler target? That's what it sounds like. Check in the right pane, if it looks good there, go to the target, look in Build Phases > Compile Sources and make sure its there, too.

Comment: The intent handler is failing because, for some reason, it's not "seeing" that custom protocol. So, the real question is why... The only other item I found with a similar result involved "adding the NSUserActivityTypes key to the main app Info.plist file with the DynamicIntent name". I don't think missing that would cause the protocol to be out of scope, though...

Comment: @asyncawait you are right! for whatever reason in the intent handler extension the intent definition had been added as a resource and not code. once it was code it was found. if you write an answer I'll give you the bounty

Comment: @leanne you were definitely on the right track, thank you so much for helping me. in the end the intent handler was part of the target but as a resource not code

Comment: Right on! Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to change the build setting in Widget extension
"Build Setting" -> search for "intent class" -> change the language to "Swift" and run again.